# Is it possible to have REF to a Silverlight class library (dll) module in ModuleCatalog.xaml

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, prism

I am working with Silverlight 4.0 and Windows Application Composite Framework (Prism).
I have created couple of modules which are Silverlight libraries so they are compiled into dlls and not xaps.

I want to register these modules into my Shell application using ModuleCatalog.xaml. If I package my modules into .xap then this approach works fine but since my modules are .dll, I am getting exception during load.

So my question is, will be possible to register silverlight module dll in ModuleCatalog.xaml?

Comment: From [this post](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/248056)   seems like it's not possible.

Comment: Yeah it seems like that all the dlls must be packaged in xap in order to ref them using catalog file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because Silverlight packages assemblies in .xap packages. Thus, if an assembly is not in the main .xap (the one of the Shell), Prism must know how to download the .xap file where it's located at to be able to download and load modules correctly.

Imagine that, if the application downloaded the module's from a server, downloading the .xap package and loading an assembly in the application is possible and easy in Silverlight, while doing it directly with a .dll is not.